# How can I apply Rolle's theorem here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

How can I use Rolle's theorem to check whether the function $f(x)=x^7+x−7$ has two real roots ?

Comment: I would be quite surprised if there were two real roots since this function is increasing.

Comment: The thing is even if I know it is increasing I don't know what t looks like so I wouldn't be able to tell if it intersects again.

Comment: @MahmoudHamra An increasing function, buy it's very definition cannot intersect with $y=0$ twice.

Comment: To be precise:  a strictly increasing function ...

Comment: Yes I just realised that, thanks !

Comment: It has one and only one real root because it is continuous increasing ($f'(x)=7x^6+1\gt 1\gt 0$) and $f(0)=-7\lt 0$ and $f(2)=128\gt 0$ So it must be $0$ somewhere in between.

Comment: it is approximative $$1.282828917425649681683114486588448882258101359838671445783610739082855826217
   808217822741469288043057$$

Answer (score 2):

By Rolle's theorem, if there are two roots, there must be a stationary point, i.e. we need a $c$ for which $f'(c) = 0$ (this $c$ must even be *between* the roots, but that is of little matter here). But $f'(x) = 7x^6 + 1 \geq 1$ can *never* be $0$. Therefore there can be no such $c$ and therefore there can be no second root of $f$.